# How to synchronize multiple threads to one?

Tags: multithreading, synchronization

I have a multithreaded application where I want to allow all but one of the threads to run synchronously. However, when a specific thread wakes up I need the rest of the threads to block.

My Current implementation is:

```
void ManyBackgroundThreadsDoingWork()
{
    AquireMutex(mutex);

    DoTheBackgroundWork();

    ReleaseTheMutex(mutex);
}


void MainThread()
{
    AquireMutex(mutex);

    DoTheMainThreadWork();

    ReleaseTheMutex(mutex);
}
```

This works, in that it does indeed keep the background threads from operating inside the critical block while the main thread is doing its work. However, There is a lot of contention for the mutex amongst the background threads even when they don't necessarily need it. The main thread runs intermittently and the background threads are able to run concurrently with each other, just not with the main thread.

What i've effectively done is reduced a multithreaded architecture to a single threaded one using locks... which is silly. What I really want is an architecture that is multithreaded for most of the time, but then waits while a small operation completes and goes back to being multithreaded.

Edit: An explanation of the problem.

What I have is an application that displays multiple video feeds coming from pcie capture cards. The pcie capture card driver issues callbacks on threads it manages into what is effectively the `ManyBackgroundThreadsDoingWork` function. In this function I copy the captured video frames into buffers for rendering. The main thread is the render thread that runs intermittently. The copy threads need to block during the render to prevent tearing of the video.

My initial approach was to simply do double buffering but that is not really an option as the capture card driver won't allow me to buffer frames without pushing the frames through system memory. The technique being used is called "DirectGMA" from AMD that allows the capture card to push video frames directly into the GPU memory. The only method for synchronization is to put a glFence and mutex around the actual rendering as the capture card will be continuously streaming data to the GPU Memory. The driver offers no indication of when a frame transfer completes. The callback supplies enough information for me to know that a frame is ready to be transferred at which point I trigger the transfer. However, I need to block transfers during the scene render to prevent tearing and artifacts in the video. The technique described above is the suggested technique from the pcie card manufacturer. The technique, however, breaks down when you want more than one video playing at a time. Thus, the question.

Comment: You will get much better answers if you explain your problem rather than your proposed solution. Because your proposed solution doesn't sound like a sensible solution to any conceivable problem. See [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Thats fair. I will add it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a lock that supports both shared and exclusive locking modes, sometimes called a [readers/writer lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock). This permits multiple threads to get read (shared) locks until one thread requests an exclusive (write) lock.